# inplace argument not working when compiling cython

Tags: python, cython

When compiling the `.pyx` files in my project directory, the `.c` files have the same path as the `.pyx` files, but the `.so` extensions are in the same folder containing my `setup.py`. Which I do not expected with the `inplace` argument. I want to compile with openmp.

**What am I missing in order to have the `.so` files in the same directories at the `.c/.pyx` files?**

Do not hesitate to ask if more details are required.

Here is the tree of my project before compiling:

```
graphene
├── ae
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── molecule.py
│   └── test.py
├── basis
│   ├── coefficients
│   │   └── sto-3g
│   │       └── C.txt
│   ├── gaussian.pxd
│   ├── gaussian.pyx
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── out1.txt
│   ├── plane_wave.py
│   ├── results2.prof
│   ├── results.prof
│   ├── test_profile.py
│   └── test.py
├── cell.py
├── constants.pxd
├── constants.py
├── constants_py.py
├── constants.pyx
├── c_ops.pxd
├── c_ops.pyx
├── energy.py
├── __init__.py
├── integral
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lebedev_quadrature
│   │   ├── lebedev_003.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_005.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_007.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_009.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_011.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_013.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_017.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_023.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_035.txt
│   │   └── lebedev_131.txt
│   └── quadrature.py
├── k_points
│   └── sampling.py
├── main.py
└── operators
    ├── electron_electron.pyx
    ├── electron_proton.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── kinetic.py
    └── overlap.py
```

The project after compilation:

```
graphene
├── ae
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── molecule.py
│   └── test.py
├── basis
│   ├── coefficients
│   │   └── sto-3g
│   │       └── C.txt
│   ├── gaussian.c
│   ├── gaussian.pxd
│   ├── gaussian.pyx
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── out1.txt
│   ├── plane_wave.py
│   ├── results2.prof
│   ├── results.prof
│   ├── test_profile.py
│   └── test.py
├── cell.py
├── constants.c
├── constants.pxd
├── constants.py
├── constants_py.py
├── constants.pyx
├── c_ops.c
├── c_ops.pxd
├── c_ops.pyx
├── energy.py
├── __init__.py
├── integral
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lebedev_quadrature
│   │   ├── lebedev_003.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_005.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_007.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_009.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_011.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_013.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_017.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_023.txt
│   │   ├── lebedev_035.txt
│   │   └── lebedev_131.txt
│   └── quadrature.py
├── k_points
│   └── sampling.py
├── main.py
└── operators
    ├── electron_electron.c
    ├── electron_electron.pyx
    ├── electron_proton.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── kinetic.py
    └── overlap.py
```

But the generated `.so` extensions are in `graphene/..`.

Here are the code of `setup.py` where the variable `parallel=True`:

```
rom setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages, find_packages, Extension
import os, sys
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy
import pythran

openmp_arg = '-fopenmp'

parallel = eval(sys.argv[1])
debug = eval(sys.argv[2])

# Recursively find all pyx/pxd files
extension_modules = []
i = 0
for root, _, files in os.walk('graphene'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".pyx"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            if parallel:
                _ext = Extension(os.path.splitext(file)[0], [path], extra_compile_args=[openmp_arg], extra_link_args=[openmp_arg])
            else:
                _ext = path #Extension(f'extension{i}', [os.path.join(root, file)])

            extension_modules.append(
                _ext
            )
            i+=1

compiler_directives = {
    'boundscheck': False,
    'cdivision': True, 
    'initializedcheck': False
}

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extension_modules, compiler_directives = compiler_directives, gdb_debug = debug),  # Compile all .pyx files in all discovered packages
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()],
    script_args = ['build_ext', '--inplace']
)
```